# Why does my program keep saying Exception in thread "main" Unresolved compilation?

Tags: java

I used the IO module for my inputs and outputs.
Sevens are considered lucky numbers. Your task is to count the number of sevens that appear within a range of numbers. Your solution should make use of looping constructs.

Ask the user for the following information, in this order:

1. The lower end of the range
2. The upper end of the range
3. Determine the number of sevens that appear in the sequence from lower end to upper
   end (inclusive).

This is the code I came up with:

```
public class LuckySevens {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int count=0;
        System.out.println("enter lower end of the range");
        int lower = IO.readInt();

        System.out.println("enter the upper end of the range");
        int upper = IO.readInt();

        if(lower>upper){
            IO.reportBadInput();
        }
        else { 
            for (int num = lower; num<=upper; num++){
                int term = num/10;
                if (num %10==7){
                    count=count++;
                    while (term>0){

                    }
                }

            }
        }


    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong that it keeps saying exception on main thread?

Comment: Add an `import` statement for `IO` perhaps.

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: What line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: error occurs on at assignment3.IO.readInt(IO.java:39)
 at assignment3.LuckySevens.main(LuckySevens.java:10)    int lower = IO.readInt();

Comment: "Unresolved Compilation" problems usually mean there's an issue with how some library (here probably `IO`) was compiled. Can you get a clean build, or even better the source, of the `IO` class? And as others have said: post the **full error message** in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sotirios is correct.  Try adding an import to the very top line of your class.  It would probably be something like...

```
import mywork.IO;
```

That being said, you may want to look into using a package declaration also.  If you have a class that is mywork.IO and you add the following package...

```
package mywork;
```

then you wouldn't need the import.

Comment: Based on the error in his comment, he isn't having trouble getting to the `IO` class.

Comment: Ah true, the question has been edited a bit.  Is there a stack trace to share?